# Unable to create Azure resource group

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

I'm getting this silly error.  I'm trying to create Resource group in Azure. I entered a valid resource group name and selected the proper subscription, but it fails some validation error and prompting me to enter a resource group name, even though I have entered a valid resource group name.  Not sure how to fix it. Any help is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried emptying the cache and hard reloading the portal? And are you sure no resource group with that name already exists?

Comment: Thanks @rickvdbosch do you mean browser cache? I'm sure that the resource group name doesn't exist.  Even I tried with few other unique names, I thought this is one off error and it will go off after some time.  I tried after a day and still, I'm getting this error.

Comment: Yes, I do mean browser cache. How many resource groups are there in the subscription? There's a default maximum of 980.

Comment: You can also try F12 and looking at the console output to see if it sheds more light on the validation failure

Comment: Finally resolved this issue by creating the resource group while creating the actual resource (instead of explicitly creating resource group).  It is not ideal way, but happy to see this workaround.  Thanks for all your comments

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to  using the same name, which is why you were unsuccessful. Try  using bash as follows:

> ```
> az group create --location
>                 --name
>                 [--managed-by]
>                 [--tags]
> ```

Example:

```
az group create -l westus -n MyResourceGroup
```